# Convert empty string to zero

Tags: python, string, casting, io

I'm doing something like this to sum up all values from start to end.

```
big_list = line.split(delim)
sum( [int(float(item)) for item in big_list[start:end]] )
```

Sometimes an element of `big_list` may be empty, in which case the conversion fails. Can I make it work with empty strings in an elegant way, without changing too much above?

Comment: are you wanting to truncate the values from float to int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that empty elements should be zero:

```
sum(int(float(item)) for item in big_list[start:end] if item)
                                                   # ^ skip over ""
```

Note that:

1. `sum` can take the generator expression as an argument, there's no need to build the list; and
2. An empty string `""` evaluates `False`-y, so this is equivalent to `if item != ""`.

Comment: I'd go with this... for completeness sake though: `int(float(item or 0))` is another option (probably more useful if a list was being built and averages were required), but for a simple `sum` - filtering makes more sense